# Problem with 32 bit libs on ubuntu 18.04.4

Tags: 18.04, 64-bit, 32-bit, mesa

The general problem with a program for ip-camera iVMS-4200. It worked until I remove all 32 bit packages from system(Ubuntu 64 bit 18.04.4). After removing 32 packages iVMS-4200 had broken. Now I install some of them, the program starts but video capturing is not showing. In a console I see many same messages `glXCreateNewContext fail port = 4`.
I think the problem is in 32 bit package, but I don't understand in which and why.
ldd on iVMS-4200 shows:

```
ldd ./iVMS-4200 
    linux-gate.so.1 (0xf7f51000)
    libhcnetsdk.so => ./PlugIns/libhcnetsdk.so (0xf7591000)
    libhpr.so => ./PlugIns/libhpr.so (0xf7370000)
    libPlayCtrl.so => ./PlugIns/libPlayCtrl.so (0xf733f000)
    libMPCtrl.so => ./PlugIns/libMPCtrl.so (0xf6fc2000)
    libsqlite3.so.0 => ./PlugIns/libsqlite3.so.0 (0xf6f12000)
    libsadp.so => ./PlugIns/libsadp.so (0xf6ccd000)
    libanalyzedata.so => ./PlugIns/libanalyzedata.so (0xf6caf000)
    libboost_thread.so.1.46.0 => ./PlugIns/libboost_thread.so.1.46.0 (0xf6c99000)
    libboost_date_time.so.1.46.0 => ./PlugIns/libboost_date_time.so.1.46.0 (0xf6c8a000)
    libQtXml.so.4 => ./PlugIns/libQtXml.so.4 (0xf6c47000)
    libQtGui.so.4 => ./PlugIns/libQtGui.so.4 (0xf6100000)
    libQtNetwork.so.4 => ./PlugIns/libQtNetwork.so.4 (0xf5fe8000)
    libQtCore.so.4 => ./PlugIns/libQtCore.so.4 (0xf5ce9000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xf5cac000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0xf5b26000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xf5a24000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf5a06000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf582a000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0xf5820000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xf5819000)
    libuuid.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0xf5810000)
    libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 (0xf57af000)
    libGLU.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1 (0xf5735000)
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0xf5720000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0xf55d6000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf7f53000)
    libGLX.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0 (0xf55b3000)
    libGLdispatch.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0 (0xf5554000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0xf5528000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0xf5522000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0xf551b000)
    libbsd.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0xf5500000)
```

And a picture in program is just a gray screen. Before my fail it shows camera's video.
[screen of gray iVMS-4200](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27lbM.png)

Can someone help please?

Comment: You haven't said what you removed; if you used `apt` like commands to remove you can look in your apt logs to see what was removed. Otherwise I'd re-install whatever made your camera software work (I don't see what that is; you haven't told us as you only mention a camera that I can see).  If it was me, I'd evaluate what you removed (via logs) and re-install what you believe is required (ie. reverse your removal; or restore everything and very slowly remove next time; and don't forget removed files can still be used by running programs; not restarted ones as Ubuntu is a multi-user system)

Comment: I have removed a lot of i386 packages. I had seen apt logs, but it has a lot of records with `:i386`. I don't wanna re-install them all again... I hope someone can tell what `glXCreateNewContext fail` means